# what happens if I pass a struct to a vararg function?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

```
void f(int count, ...){
    //whatever
}

struct somestruct{
    size_t a, b, c;
};

int main() {
    somestruct s;
    f(1, s);    //what is actually passed?
}
```

Is the entire `struct` copied and passed on the stack? If so are copy constructors called? Is the pointer passed? Is this safe?

Comment: You must be asking about C++; C does not have copy constructores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you pass an lvalue, the lvalue to rvalue conversion will be done, which means calling the copy constructor to copy the object into a new copy and passing that as an argument.

Comment: Well... but if you still have the constraint that the type must be trivially copyable (and you do, `g++` outputs an error otherwise), then your answer and billz's are equivalent... or not?

Comment: @LorenzoPistone no. the copy constructor may be deleted or private. it will not necessarily be non-trivial, but calling it will be ill-formed.

Answer (score 1):

`void f(...)` is using bit-wised copy. No default constructor or copy constructor will be generated for your `somestruct` as it only has C++ build-in types.

```
Is this safe?
```

Yes, this is perfectly safe.

I'll refer you to 'Inside C++ Object Model' `chapter 2 The Semantics of Constructors`

Comment: I noticed now that the struct has to be trivially copyable.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: the struct has to be a POD type.